# DateDiff for every row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two Columns

```
Move In Date                     Move Out Date
2/24/2011                         2/25/2014
```

I have similar data for 20,000 rows. I want another column

Length of Stay

(Difference between `MoveOutDate` and `MoveIn` Date) only in Years.

but I need the query to run for every row in the table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT MoveInDate,MoveOutDate,DATEDIFF(year,MoveInDate,MoveOutDate) As Years
FROM Table1
```

**[DateDiff](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)**

Comment: Your second version ignores leap years and so may be subtly wrong at times. Even if you try to correct it (to 365.2425, say) there'll still be points at which it's incorrect.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes i'' accept it and i ll take back

Answer (score 1):

```
select Move_In_Date,Move_Out_Date,datediff(year,Move_In_Date,Move_Out_Date) as year_diff
from yourTable
```